# Prism WPF Closing view and dispose autowired ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

In short the behaviour i want to accomplish is LOGIN->LOGOUT->LOGIN

My application starts with a login view. After authentication, it close and the MainView open:

```
public void Authenticated(){
    MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
    main.Show();
    if (Application.Current.Windows.Count > 1) {
        Application.Current.Windows[0].Close();
    }
    this.CloseAction();
}
```

*the CloseAction is just an action variable which close from the codebehind like so*

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        if ( (this.DataContext as MainWindowViewModel)!.CloseAction == null )
            (this.DataContext as MainWindowViewModel)!.CloseAction = new Action(this.CloseH);
    }

    private void CloseH() {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

My main cointains also two view regions pushed from the logic of the MainViewViewModel (THOSE TWO ARE USERCONTROLS)

```
_regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("FileTreeRegion", typeof(FileTree));
_regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("FileDetailsRegion", typeof(FileDetails));
```

At some point if i need to logout i run the function

```
public void Logout(){
   Login login = new Login();
   login.Show();
   if (Application.Current.Windows.Count > 1) {
       Application.Current.Windows[0].Close();
   }
   this.CloseAction();
   // _eventAggregator.GetEvent<AppMessageLogout>().Publish();
   // _regionManager.Regions.ToList().ForEach((r) => r.RemoveAll());
}
```

But when i retry to login, my views viewmodels (the usercontrols FileTree and FileDetails) are called two times (debugging the constructor method).
The previously commented lines are two attempts to solve the issue without success:

- using a publish/subscribe command with a Disposable in the UserControl (I disposed only the register commands in the viewmodel since there isn't a `Close()` in a UserControl)
- trashing all the views in the regionManager to avoid garbageCollection. Altought i guess this is useless since, as i read online, the parentWindow of the views is the MainWindow and when it close also the views do

The ViewModels are all autowired with Prism in the xaml files.

Comment: What is the problem? This doesn't make sense... removing the views is required to make them eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: aren't the views tied to the MainWindow? so when i close the main also the views die... However the problem (the double call to the constructors) remains... both lines are failed attempts not solutions

Comment: There isn't enough info here to reproduce the issue. But have a look at Prism Navigation. Instead of just registering your view with region, look at registering your view for navigation. This should avoid double call to the constructor. Have a look at this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=anoK10sSPvE